# How to unit test a Controller action using the Response property in ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In an **ASP.NET Core 1.0 (MVC 6)** project I have a Controller action method in which I use the `Response` property to set a header:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    ...

    Response.Headers.Add("Location", location);

    ...
}
```

I tried to implement a unit test for this action method, but the value of the `Response` property is null.

This was easy to solve in the previous versions of ASP.NET, because the `Response` property had a setter, and you could simply set its value to a new `HttpResponse` instance during a unit test.

But in ASP.NET 5 `Response` does not have a setter, only a getter.
How can I set a value for `Response` in a unit test?

**UPDATE**: Just to make clear: this question is about **ASP.NET Core 1.0**. The other question linked as duplicate is about ASP.NET 4, and the Api changed since then so the answer there does not apply to this question.

Comment: I'm aware of and familiar with mocking.
The problem here is that I can't find a way with the API of ASP.NET to assign a mock object to the `Response` property.

Comment: You need to mock the whole context, and within that mock the response and its headers collection. Then use this to populate the controller's ControllerContext (which is where the controller gets its Request and Response properties).

Comment: Yes, that used to be the case in MVC 5, but now in MVC 6 the `ControllerContext` does not exist any more.

Comment: Doesn't the `ControllerBase` class contain a [`ControllerContext`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L108) with a setter? You can set the `ControllerContext` to a mocked one with a mock HttpContext, which in turn has a mock Response etc... If you are not inheriting from ControllerBase, you won't even have a property `Response` (unless you add it yourself)

Comment: Daniel: that was the case in ASP.NET 4, but in ASP.NET 5 (or ASP.NET Core 1) there is no `ControllerBase` class and `ControllerContext` property.

Comment: @MarkVincze in my comment you have a link to the ControllerBase class in the officiak ASP MVC Core repository! Whether you decide to create a controller that inherits from it or not is up to you. (But if you don't, just make sure you write your controller class in a testable way, like injecting an IHttpContextAccessor)

Comment: Daniel that link points to the dev branch of the aspnet repository, that class is not part of neither the master branch, neither the package distributed as a Nuget package.
In the current version of ASP.NET, the base class is `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller`, and that does not have the `ControllerContext` property.

Comment: I see, in RC1 they are called [`Controller`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs#L111) and `ActionContext`. I basically wanted to clarify that as in MVC 5, in MVC Core there is a base class with a way of setting the HttpContext and Request properties (although indirectly through another property). I would start making my mind about the upcoming changes though, [`ControllerBase` and `ControllerContext`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L108) :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info! :) In the meantime I posted an answer with a working solution, I guess in the new version simply the `ActionContext` will have to be replaced by using the `ControllerContext`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found one solution to the problem, however, it's a bit tedious and convoluted, so I'm still interested in seeing a simpler approach, if any exists.

The `Controller` gets the value of its `Response` property from `ActionContext.HttpContext`. What makes mocking this difficult is that all these properties are read-only, so we cannot just simply set a mock value, we have to create mocks for every object in play.

The part of the Response I needed in my test was the `Headers` collection, so I had to create and use the following mocks to make that availale. (Mocking is done with [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4).)

```
var sut = new MyController();

// The HeaderDictionary is needed for adding HTTP headers to the response.
// This needs a couple of different Mocks, because many properties in the class model are read-only.
var headerDictionary = new HeaderDictionary();
var response = new Mock<HttpResponse>();
response.SetupGet(r => r.Headers).Returns(headerDictionary);

var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
httpContext.SetupGet(a => a.Response).Returns(response.Object);

sut.ActionContext = new ActionContext()
{
    HttpContext = httpContext.Object
};
```

This is a bit more code than what I'd like to see to mock a single property, but I couldn't find any better approach yet, and it seems to be working nicely.

Comment: To have less code, you should check NSubstitute (http://nsubstitute.github.io/)

Comment: Efaruk, I'm using Moq as a mocking framework. What exactly would NSubstitute provide which Moq is not capable of? (Also, does NSubstitute already support CoreCLR?)

Comment: @MarkVincze Did you ever find a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: Hey @ShawnMclean, no I haven't found any nicer solution, I'm still using this—pretty verbose—approach.

Comment: In case anyone is still looking at this.  `ActionContext` doesn't exist in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller`.  It has been replaced by `ControllerContext` reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286530/actioncontext-gone-in-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controller

Comment: You could throw this in an extension method `public static T WithControllerContext<T>(this T controller) where T : Controller {/*...*/}` so you can re-use it only when needed `controller = new MyController(/*...*/).WithControllerContext();`.

Comment: To have less code, there is no need to mock HttpContext and HttpContext.Response. Just create a new DefaultHttpContext object, which will have a non-null Response object with non-null Headers property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ResponseWrapper with virtual properties and you can mock it and expect one call for virtual AddHeader method with "Location" parameter. 
**Relevant Question** Here: [MOQ - Mocking MVC Controller's Response.Cookies.Clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098585/moq-mocking-mvc-controllers-response-cookies-clear)

**You can check those examples: for ASP.Net 5 MVC 6:**

- http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/unit-testing-controllers-aspnet5
- http://dotnetthoughts.net/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-6-applications/

Another option if you want to try NancyFx(http://nancyfx.org/) (https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy) it's quite easy: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Testing-your-application

> For example - if you were testing a login page and wanted to verify
>   that the user was redirected to an “error” page if they entered
>   incorrect credentials you could use the ShouldHaveRedirectedTo
>   assertion:
>
> ```
> [Fact] public void Should_redirect_to_login_with_error_details_incorrect() {
>     // Given
>     var bootstrapper = new DefaultNancyBootstrapper();
>     var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);
>
>     // When
>     var response = browser.Post("/login/", (with) => {
>         with.HttpRequest();
>         with.FormValue("Username", "username");
>         with.FormValue("Password", "wrongpassword");
>     });
>
>     // Then
>     response.ShouldHaveRedirectedTo("/login?error=true&username=username");
> ```
>
> }

There is more:

> ```
> [Fact]
> public void Should_display_error_message_when_error_passed()
> {
>     // Given
>     var bootstrapper = new DefaultNancyBootstrapper();
>     var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);
>
>     // When
>     var response = browser.Get("/login", (with) => {
>         with.HttpRequest();
>         with.Query("error", "true");
>     });
>
>     // Then
>     response.Body["#errorBox"]
>             .ShouldExistOnce()
>             .And.ShouldBeOfClass("floatingError")
>             .And.ShouldContain(
>                 "invalid",
>                 StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
> }
> ```

Comment: Yep, I could create an abstraction just for adding a header to the response, but it feels like an overkill, so I would like to avoid that if possible.
Thanks for the example, but I want to use MVC, so the NancyFX stuff doesn't apply.

Comment: Also, the example you sent is using the `ControllerContext` property, which does not exist any more in MVC 6.
I expect this to be possible to be done with MVC 6, just the properties I need to use were probably moved around a little bit.

Comment: I have edited my answer and also you have ActionContext for replacement...

Comment: I checked the links you sent, but they don't have information about mocking the `Response` property. The other link in the answer is for ASP.NET 4. I'll try mocking with the `ActionContext`, but that won't be straightforward either, since the `Response` property doesn't have a setter there either.

Comment: You don't need setter; HttpResponseBase has virtual properties you can create a Wrapper class and you can mock HttpResponseBase: 

`public class ResponseWrapper
    {
        private readonly HttpResponseBase _response;

        public ResponseWrapper(HttpResponseBase response)
        {
            _response = response;
        }
    }`

You can check for mocking in mvc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534953/nsubstitute-mocking-the-request-response-object-inside-a-mvc-web-api-controlle

Comment: Efaruk I don't see how that `ResponseWrapper` would make the situation any easier. The difficulty is mocking the properties of `Controller`, not the `HttpResponse`.

Comment: There is no easier way for your choices @MarkVincze!!! Did you gave my answer down point !?