# ActionContext gone in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I cant find ActionContext  in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller

after i changed my Version to AspNetCore 1.0.0-preview1

this is Controller class (after Change):

[image]

And from "**Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc**" before change :

[image]

and code from old method before update :

```
this.Agent = ControllerInfo.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
this.IP = ControllerInfo.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.LocalIpAddress?.ToString(); 
this.RemoteIP = ControllerInfo.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
this.Refrence = ControllerInfo.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() 
    + "/" + ControllerInfo.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I replaced **ActionContext** with **ControllerContext**, and it works for me.
I don't know if it's an official migration step, though.

Comment: It provides a possible solution to Andrey Markovs' problem, as it was the solution for my problem that brought me here in the first place. I don't see how deleting my comment and downvoting it was productive - is it really better for this question to be unanswered?!

Comment: @ManoDestra How does this not provide an answer?

Comment: "I replaced it with ControllerContext" - replaced what exactly? There's no code in this question nor sufficient explanation of how to resolve the issue. With some editing, it could be improved though :)

Comment: This is the correct answer. It seemed clear, but "it" refers to the ActionContext property indicated in the question. So: replace ActionContext with ControllerContext in RC2.

Comment: It works because `ControllerContext` is a subclass of `ActionContext`.

Answer (score 24):

You can inject `IActionContextAccessor` to your class. It provides access to the action context.

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

Use it:

```
private readonly IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor

public FooController(IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor)
{
    this.actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
}
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793).

Comment: This is strange. I just upgraded my codebase to .net core 3.1 and after that, I started getting null for IActionContextAcessor (I had no issues with .net core 2.2). The issue was gone after I explicitly added the line you mentioned here. I wonder why this has anything to do with .net core 3.1.... Thanks.

Comment: This actually helped me resolve my other problem of passing the actionContextAccessor to my Service Layer

Answer (score 3):

In .NET core 3.1 at least, ControllerBase has a property Url that works as a UrlHelper so you don't have to make one yourself.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52537244/4172413

Comment: .net core migration users should use this solution instead.